# Can I use two 30A breakers together for a 60A water pump?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, pump

I have a 240v water pump connected to a 60-amp 240v breaker. Can I use two 30-amp 120v breakers pinned together in place of the 60-amp breaker?

Comment: What, if any, troubleshooting steps have you performed, and what were the results of those steps? Why are you replacing the breaker? Please [edit] that information into your question.

Comment: Two would just pop instantly..  Maybe you mean four?   That's not allowed.  In either case the jerry-rigging required to connect them to your 60A wiring might catch fire before anything else went wrong.    It would be interesting to know why you want to do this.  You can Edit the question to add more information.

Comment: Note that a circuit breaker doesn't have a "voltage" in the sense you use in the question.  A 120V circuit has two wires, only one of which is protected by a breaker. (The neutral is not directly protected).    A 240V circuit has both its wires protected.  A "240V" 60A breaker is in fact two 60A breakers intended to be used in a 240V circuit.  But the two component breakers are not inherently 120V or 240V ones.  They are just 60A breakers, and you can't replace them with 30A ones, neither with a pair of "120V" 30A ones nor with a purpose-built 30A 240V one.

Comment: Please stop what you're doing right now, and phone an electrician.

Comment: Where in the world are you?  You said 220V but this has been edited to 240V on the assumption you are in the United States.  Are you?

Comment: Also, what is the actual power rating of that motor?  14kW is an absolutely enormous amount of power for a water pump in your home.  Either the breaker is extremely oversized or you're operating a factory in your garage.  What in the world do you need such a colossal water pump for??  I have pumps half that size running closed-loop cooling on industrial machines that consume as much power as a dozen average homes.  It boggles the mind what you would need that for.  You could run an olympic sized swimming pool with a pump that size.

Comment: Some people have to deal with submersible pumps in really deep wells, at their houses, @J... Or pehaps they need enoungh water for the cows, not quite as deep.

Comment: @Ecnerwal No way - not even close.  I've lived in rural areas and have been in places with 300ft+ deep wells - you don't need 15HP for that.  You barely need 1HP for that.  Cows don't drink 400 gallons per minute at 80psi.

Comment: @J... Feeding cows 400G/min @ 80 PSI is how science gets those spherical cows used in thought experiments.

Comment: @Criggie Indeed, and if OP is explosively hydroforming cows then they're probably at least some type of commercial or industrial facility, in which case DIY electrics is a big huge no-no.

Comment: For some odd reason, I feel like this is a homework question, which (if that's the case) would explain the numbers...

Answer (score 43):

No, and the level of "not understand what you are doing" is concerning.

60A at 240V (220 is at least 50 years out of date) is also 60A at 120V, twice. Two 30A 120V breakers are exactly equivalent to a 30A at 240V breaker in terms of "size" but the 240V breaker ensures "common trip" which is desirable from a safety point of view.

Any replacement breaker must be **UL-listed** for installation into the panel in question - the same brand and model, or one that has been specifically tested and listed as being compatible with that panel - "it fits" is not nearly good enough, and problems from non-compatible breakers could get ugly fast with 60A breakers (lots of power available to melt poorly fitting connections typical of using the wrong type of breaker.)

Pretty sure you won't be finding any 60A at 120V breakers to pin together, so just get the correct breaker if you need to replace the breaker. Of course if the problem is with the pump or wiring rather than the breaker, throwing parts at a problem only solves it if you happen to throw the right parts.

Comment: +1 and agreed, but some of this assumes OP is in the US.  220V is standard in dozens of countries.  UL only applies to the US.  We don't know where in the world OP is.

Comment: The OP mentioned using "2 120V breakers" which puts the OP firmly in US/Canada or somewhere else (not many) that use our split-phase 120V-N-120V power sytem.

Comment: Most probably, but there are countries with 110/220 split phase (Haiti, Taiwan...)

Answer (score 18):

**The right breaker is $12.**

(I'm being generous here) you are confused about how 120/240V split-phase works.  A lot of people think you multiply **amps** by 2 when going from 1 phase to 2 phases, or the other way around.  Not at all.

The different phases and neutral simply let you pick the voltage - 120V vs 240V.  The **amperage**  is exactly what it says on the tin - a 30A circuit uses a 30A breaker, a 60A circuit uses a 60A breaker.  Which are $12 by the way.

Yes, it's a double breaker, but really, all circuits could be double breakers.  We just *don't bother putting a circuit breaker on neutral wires*, so in North America that means 120V circuits get to use single breakers.

### But yes, you can *handle-tie* singles to drive 240V-only loads.

You need to use an approved handle-tie, not a nail.  They are $3.  But yes, you can take two 30A 120V breakers and make a 240V breaker, it will be a 30A breaker though lol.

This does not work for 120/240V loads which include a neutral wire, such as dryers or ranges, which require a feature called "common trip" (one side trips, all do).  Why not?

Because the handle-tie is only for the protection of maintainers.  To make sure the maintainer turns off *the whole circuit* and doesn't leave half of it energized out of unawareness.

Handle-ties do not provide common trip because breakers are designed to "trip free", i.e. trip even if the handle is held in the on position. Such as by a locking kit, that you might put on a fire alarm breaker.  Yeah, that's legit.

Comment: Unless they're planning on putting two 30 A breakers in parallel, in which case the current carrying capacity would add up, ... in principle. (Still not a good idea.)

Comment: @ilkkachu agreed, a matched pair in parallel for single phase 240V is not unheard of, they will of course cascade trip the first being subject to race conditions. But if they are not balanced one will pass a greater share of current and they will both trip below 60A.

Comment: First time I saw the locking thing for a fire alarm breaker I was immediately highly suspicious of what the residents were up to.....

Answer (score 2):

No you should not.

1. It increases the risk of failure.
   There would be 2 components that could fail instead of 1. And no matter how they are connected they will be working outside their intended scope.
2. The functionality achieved with 2 breakers would be different than expected with 1 breaker. It is uncommon to be expected to operate 2 breakers instead of 1 for such a pump. This could expose equipment, and people to risk.
3. It would be against regulations / standards in many countries. There are specific regulations regarding breakers and cables for AC loads connected on the grid. There is a lot of science and experience built into these regulations and standards.

Answer (score 0):

This is a single phase, 240V pump rated at 60A or Max 60A?

You should check the manufacturers documentation as you would not use a 60A fuse typically in any case as the fuse must carry the starting load, regardless of induction choking the inrush.

But let us say that 60A is recommended.

It is not unheard of to use use a matched pair in parallel, one of them will always be more sensitive, and one will always carry slightly more than half the current.

It is not recommended as there will be a delay as they cascade, and someone will invariably swap one out for an unmatched one or even an improper value.

If it your own rail and you are testing, it is arguably acceptable.  Otherwise, it is not.

HIGH VALUE sand filled fuses already have parallel elements.

https://youtu.be/0mGhhdPgXG8  (I am not this person).

Comment: There are no fuses in this question.

Answer (score -2):

Simple answer : **DON'T DO THAT**

If you put two 120V 60A breakers in serial and there something like a 61A current, the two breakers will never open at the same time. When the first breaker will start opening it will begin to reduce the current. However as side effect this can prevent the opening of the second breaker. As result that 110V breaker will receive an inductive 220V.
What will happen in that state ? There two cases :

- if your very lucky : the breaker will be damaged.
- in most case : **it will start fire**.

As side note :

- is it a 60A nominal current or 60A max current ?
- Never use a circuit breaker based on the motor max amperage (it will not protect the motor for overloads)
- avoid to use a "normal" circuit breaker to protect a motor. it can break when the motor start.

Always use a *motor circuit breaker* adapted to the nominal current. And set it the the exact nominal intensity (or little less).

For info Schneider public prices in US are :

- 180.00 USD for the 6A motor circuit breaker
- 466.00 USD for the 60A motor circuit breaker

Note : theses are designed for three-phase electric power at 400V. So they are a 'little' oversized for a 220V two-phase motor. But this will be safe.
However search for an adapted protection in your country.

Additional note : even if it's less risky, the same logic also happen in putting many circuits-breakers in parallel trying to sum the total nominal current. (not the maximal current) One difference : instead of preventing the other breaker from opening, the first breaker breaker will instant transfer all the load to the second breaker leaving it alone to do all the job.

Answer to @TooTea
First : thanks for your comment

> Just FYI, you should edit any additions into your answer (using the "edit" link under the answer) instead of posting a comment.

Merged

> First, there are no "120V" circuit breakers

I live in Europe where there only 230V an 400V. And there two different circuit breakers for theses two voltages. I simply assumed is was the same in US for 110V.

> once one of them trips, the circuit is interrupted and not current can flow anymore. (And no, 120V vs 240V has no effect on the ability of a breaker to extinguish the arc during a high-current trip.)

It has. If the load is inductive (like a pump) the current don't stop instantly. (that why there electrical arc on opening and it's how welding stations works). Even if the voltage across the arc only depend on it's length, the network voltage continue to push the current inside it, meaning more power to dissipate.

Comment: Just FYI, you should edit any additions into your answer (using the "edit" link under the answer) instead of posting a comment. Also, I suspect the reason your answer got downvoted is because the first paragraph simply doesn't make any sense. First, there are no "120V" circuit breakers, so putting them in series doesn't make any sense. Second, if you do put them in series, once one of them trips, the circuit is interrupted and not current can flow anymore. (And no, 120V vs 240V has no effect on the ability of a breaker to extinguish the arc during a high-current trip.)

Comment: Answered in the main message. (Sorry for the fails with previous answers, it was almost the first time i try to really use a stack____ website.)

Comment: Everything in the first paragraph is wrong. That's not how any of this works.

Comment: The first paragraph is only wrong in a perfect world. In practice there always some difference between breakers and they can take different time to trigger when the overload is small. Note : All of that happen at the millisecond scale.